# Is it possible to launch bootstrap modal on pagination click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I would like to acheive a goal but I do not know if it is possible. I have a pagination, instead of navigation to a new page after click I would like it to open a  modal made with bootstrap. The modal opens properly when I remove the pagination, but it cannot work with the pagination. How can I change the pagination jquery function to make both the pagination and the modal work together ?

Or Is there another way to do that, any suggestion would be appreciated .

Thanks

1- Pagination

```
<a id="pagination-obstetrico"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view" href="<?php echo base_url("admin/data_ssr_by_id/$row->idssr")?>"></a>
```

2- The modal call

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ver_ssr"  role="dialog" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
<div class="modal-content" >

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

3- the pagination function

```
$('#pagination-obstetrico').twbsPagination({
totalPages: 5,
// the current page that show on start
startPage: 1,

// maximum visible pages
visiblePages: 5,

initiateStartPageClick: true,

// template for pagination links
href: false,

// variable name in href template for page number
hrefVariable: '{{number}}',

// Text labels
first: 'First',
prev: 'Previous',
next: 'Next',
last: 'Last',

// carousel-style pagination
loop: false,

// callback function
onPageClick: function (event, page) {
   $('.page-active').removeClass('page-active');
  $('#page'+page).addClass('page-active');
},

// pagination Classes
paginationClass: 'pagination',
nextClass: 'next',
prevClass: 'prev',
lastClass: 'last',
firstClass: 'first',
pageClass: 'page',
activeClass: 'active',
disabledClass: 'disabled'

});
```

5- [External resources for the pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQwEv.png)

6- My parent page

- The list of buttons is the pagination, the parent page is a form, the pagination is the number of times users have filled the form. When I click on a pagination link I should open a modal to edit the data relevent to the pagination id.
- [image]

7- The modal shotscreen when I am not using the pagination, note that when I use the pagination the modal cannot launch.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: *«but it cannot work with the pagination»*... Do you have an idea why? Some console errors?

Comment: I think data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ver_ssr" are out of the pagination function.

Comment: The modal's HTML markup should be outside the `#pagination-obstetrico` container.

Comment: I just tried it, but stil the same ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a start

```js
$('#page-selection').bootpag({
  total: 10,
  href: "#pro-page-{{number}}"
}).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num) {
  $("#content").html("Page " + num); // some ajax content loading...
});

$(function() {
  $("#page-selection .pagination.bootpag li a")
    .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
    .attr('data-target', '#myModal');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootpag/1.0.7/jquery.bootpag.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
<div id="page-selection"></div>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="phpContent"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Addendum Per OP Comment:

> I must use a link to open the modal, each modal page is the result of a query according the id in the href, like : idssr")?>">. How can I do it like this ?

First php script is server side. So all your links are known by the time the page is rendered.  Bootpag renders client side dynamically so ideally it would be nice if on initialization you could map a php defined javascript construct that the bootpag init could access to map the urls to pager buttons

One way to do this would be to write some php script that creates a javascript simple object such that the end result looks like this:

```
    var pagerUrls = {
        "1": "url1",
        "2": "url2",
        "3": "url3",
        ...
        "n": "urln"
    };
```

Then during initialization you could do this:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#page-selection .pagination.bootpag li a")
            .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
            .attr('data-target', '#myModal');

        $("#page-selection .pagination.bootpag li a")
            .each( function(){
                $(this).data('url', pagerUrls[ $(this).data("lp") ] );
            });


    });
```

With the buttons now set you can use a "triggered Modal" see [Varying modal content based on trigger button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target) for more information.

This would allow one modal to display dynamic content based on a triggering button.  It makes use of Bootstrap Modal `show.bs.modal` event which I use here to make an ajax call based on a given url.

> NB: This ajax call is simplistic as I have no idea what your urls return, I'm assuming html, but you would need to set up the appropriate ajax settings for your needs.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // Button that triggered the modal
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); 

  var ajaxOptions = {
    url: button.data('url'),
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "html"
  };

  var request = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Results from ' + ajaxOptions.url );
  modal.find('.modal-body #phpContent').val(request);
});
```

> NB: none of this code is tested and is only intended to show a concept.  you will have to put in the effort to debug it.

But now I have a question for you.
This is a LOT of effort to make use of a modal to display dynamic content when you consider that bootpag is intended to fill a `div` with exactly that.

Is there a reason you are using a modal?

Happy Programming!

Comment: Thank you so much fnostro for your reply I really appreciate it, it teaches me indeed. I was trying to modify your codes because, I must use a link to open the modal, each modal page is the result of a query according the id in the href, like : <a  href="<?php echo base_url("admin/data_ssr_by_id/$row->idssr")?>"></a>. How can I do it like this ? thanks

Comment: there is a lot to consider here, I'll add to my answer to clarify based on your comment.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I am bound to use a modal because my parent page structure requires me that. I am going to update my question so that you see the screen shot of my parent page